# 9 pole mini din identification

Tags: plug, mini, din

I need to buy a 9 pole mini din plug (male) to create a ps2 -> quadrature mouse adapter but I'm a little concerned the socket I'm connecting to is non-standard:

[image: Rear of an Archimedes 440/1 keyboard]
[[image: Angled view displaying notch better2]

The reason I think this is the top 3 pins are not evenly distributed and the data sheets I look at for ordering online have them evenly distributed.

So my questions are:

1. Is this socket standard?
2. Are the datasheets wrong?
3. Could I buy a 10 pin, and just pull one of the pins out of the plug?

Comment: The middle row is also not evenly distributed, although it's close enough that you could probably force it.

Comment: So are you saying the socket in the photo is non-standard @DaveTweed?

Comment: No, I'm just making an observation based on your photo. What exactly is the piece of equipment?

Comment: search for mini din connector leads to https://www.ebay.com/itm/2pcs-mini-DIN-MD9-9-pin-plug-Connector-soldering-Plastic-Handle-for-Promedia-GMX/362151055365?_trkparms=aid%3D111001%26algo%3DREC.SEED%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D225080%26meid%3Dfccfad9ec85146c993579d6cf7d4c05c%26pid%3D100970%26rk%3D2%26rkt%3D2%26mehot%3Dnone%26sd%3D282039528982%26itm%3D362151055365%26pmt%3D0%26noa%3D1%26pg%3D2380057&_trksid=p2380057.c100970.m5481&_trkparms=pageci%3Acf8c3cd9-af50-11ea-856a-74dbd1806a3a%7Cparentrq%3Ab9ed0e6c1720ad4a4cee0694fff3cdb0%7Ciid%3A1   ... it is for Promedia GMX

Comment: @DaveTweed this is the back of an Archimedes computer keyboard - and you're looking at the mouse socket. In this case it's a 440/1 system built around 1987 I think. The Archimedes line of computers used a non-standard mouse system called 'quadrature' - really weird. I'm using my Arduino to translate a ps/2 optical mouse into the right protocol for this. I've ordered a 9 pin minidin with flylead from RS components, it wasn't cheap but I didn't fancy soldering the mini-din.

The Archimedes was one of the first 32 bit personal computers and was the first to use an ARM chip. Very cool, v.fast.

Comment: @jsotola - I live in the UK and didn't want to have to try and solder something up that small so I went for a pre-wired one from RS.. it wasn't cheap unfortunately.

Comment: Update: the minidin arrived - it does indeed fit nicely. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this socket standard?

Pinwise, yes, it seems to me that all 9-pin mini din connectors are that way, with an uneven first row, which is also found in the 10-pin model. If there are no differences in dimension, there shouldn't be any problems using a 9-pin din on it. Although that happens to be my experience, the fact that the datasheets indicate otherwise would make me second-guess myself.

Although, it does not seem to feature the two little notches near the bottom, common in the mini din connector, which might make it incompatible.(EDIT: A new picture shows that it does indeed have the notches.)

> Are the datasheets wrong?

Well, it seems to me that they *could*, but it is hard to say, really.  You should look for a datasheet with measurements to see if it really is non-standard.

> Could I buy a 10 pin, and just pull one of the pins out of the plug?

I don't think the two bottom row pins would necessary align if you remove the middle one of a 10-pin. But perhaps with some force you could, although it would not be ideal.

Comment: Note - I think the notch doesn't show in the photo clearly.. the top is cut out to a depth of a few mm within the circle.

Comment: I meant [these two notches near the bottom](https://p.globalsources.com/IMAGES/PDT/BIG/007/B1094082007.jpg).

Comment: Thanks - it has those, I've added another photo that shows them much more clearly (in hindsight that first photo was really misleading!)

Comment: Looking at it now, I see no reason to believe that a standard 9-pin wouldn't work. If need be, the 10-pin might even work in a pinch.

Comment: Perfect, thanks for your help!